# Query a Redis Cluster

Tags: database, redis, redis-cluster

I am new to Redis, and I'm trying to find a proper solution to a major requirement.

I am developing an online mobile game, so I would need to keep some game-related data for each player.
A common use case is getting some player's data upon their login.
I would also need a method for segmenting my players: meaning I need to easily query all my players' data. e.g. "Get all players that have less than 100 coins and did not login for 7 days" or "Get all players that are level 5-7 and logged in today", etc.
Another requirement is being able to tell, when a player log in, which segments they belong (but that sounds quite easy)

I want to use transactions to minimize data loss, and for that all data that is updated within a transaction should reside on the same node (Redis requirement).

How should I approach this?

A method I thought of to query those values is to keep them in a **sorted set**, that way I can quite easily query for "players with level 5-7" and "playes that did not login for 7 days" by sorted set's commands and intersect those lists for "players with level 5-7 and did not login for 7 days"

Problem with this methodology is that I'm forced to keep all players' data on the same node, thus canceling some cluster benefits.

I could also keep player's info in hash/string fields, and just iterate all players when need to evaluate a segment, but that sounds extremely wasteful.

I know I can upgrade my Redis to have RedisSearch, and that might ease up these processes, but I'm trying to think of a solution that is less expensive.